# Why does initializing pointer of class A through method in class B in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault

I have the following code: ([live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5c911ebef99ec62))

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA{
    public:
    ClassA(int i) : m_int(i){};

    int m_int;
};

class Master{
    public:
    Master(){};

    ~Master(){
        delete m_classMain;
    }

    ClassA* m_classMain;

    template<typename T>
    void mem(T* t, int i){
        t = new T(i);  
    }

    void test() {
        mem(m_classMain,3);
    }

    int get_i() const{
        return m_classMain->m_int;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Master* master = new Master();
    master->test();

    std::cout << master->get_i() << std::endl;
    delete master;
}
```

I would like to initialize the object `ClassA* m_classMain` through the method `mem(T* t, int i)` which is a template method.

For some reason I only get a segmentation fault. I think `t = new T(i)` might be the problem here, but I can not figure why (unfortunately I do not have a debugger at hand).

Comment: This is a common problem. Use `mem(T** t, int i)`, `*t = new T(i)`, and `mem(&m_classMain,3);` [Updated demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d671397d4b1e9239)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your posted code, the member variable `m_classMain` is not initialized. Calling `delete` on it is cause for undefined behavior.

The call

```
    mem(m_classMain,3);
```

does not initialize `m_classMain` since you are passing it by value. To initialize it in `mem`, you'll have to pass it by reference.

```
template<typename T>
  void mem(T*& t, int i){ //T*& t, not T* t.
    t = new T(i);  
}
```

---

As a matter of good coding practice, make sure that all member variables are initialized in the constructor(s).

```
Master() : m_classMain(nullptr) {};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the `t` parameter of the mem() function by value.  It gets destroyed on function exit.  Consider passing by reference, or accessing the member directly from the member function.